# Validation only working for the first input field of loop

Tags: angular, typescript

I have created a dynamic form using Angular that allows users to input email addresses. The user should not be allowed to add another empty field until the previous field is completed. Currently my code validates the first field correctly but will add a new field if the second, third, etc. is blank even though it will still fire the error alert.

Here is the HTML:

```
<ion-item id="row" *ngFor="let emailinput of emailinputs ; let i = index">
  <ion-label fixed id="label">
    Email
  </ion-label>
  <ion-input type="email" id="email" placeholder="jdoe@gmail.com" [(ngModel)]="emailinputs[i].email"></ion-input>
</ion-item>

<div padding>
  <button (click) = "addnewemail(emailinputs)" ion-button full color="nudgetprim" block>Add</button>
  <button (click) = "sendinvite(emailinputs.email)" ion-button full color="nudgetprim" block>Invite</button>
</div>
```

Here is the TS:

```
addnewemail() {
  console.log(this.emailinputs)
  for(var a in this.emailinputs){
    if (this.emailinputs[a].email==null || this.emailinputs[a].email=="" || !this.emailinputs[a].email.includes("@") || !this.emailinputs[a].email.includes("."))
    {
      let alert = this.alerCtrl.create({
        title: 'Error!',
        message: 'There was an error with an email address you entered.',
        buttons: ['Ok']
      });
      alert.present()
    }
    else {
      var newItem = this.emailinputs.length;
      this.emailinputs.push({'id' : 'row' + newItem, 'name' : 'row' + newItem, 'email': ''});
    }
  }
}
```

How can I make this work for every input, not just the first?

Comment: Don't use the same `id` for multiple elements.

Comment: Why not use reactive forms and a FormArray?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are now iterating the whole array, which means, if the code hits an item in your array that actually has values, it will add a new item in the array. What you want to check, is that the last item in your array does not have an empty (or invalid) email value:

```ts
addnewemail() {
  // get last item!
  let item = this.emailinputs[this.emailinputs.length-1];
    if (item.email == null || 
        item.email == "" || 
        !item.email.includes("@") || 
        !item.email.includes(".")) {
      // alert
    }
    else {
      // add new item
    } 
}
```

**[StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/ionic-fot5qn?file=pages%2Fhome%2Fhome.html)**

You could also try and use actual email validation, preferably making a reactive form (like suggested in comment) with `Validators.email`.